# Summation of two equicontinuous family of functions

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, equicontinuity

Let $X$ be a metric space. Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are families of real valued functions. If $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are equicontinuous, is $\mathcal{F}+\mathcal{G}$ equicontinuous, too?

I think the answer is yes, because the elements of equicontinuous family of functions is continuous and summation of two continuous functions is continuous.

This is my attempt:
Let $\varepsilon>0$.
Since $\mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuos, then there exists $\delta_1>0$, such that for all $x,y\in X$ with $d(x,y)<\delta_1$,we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$, for all $f\in \mathcal{F}$.

And since $\mathcal{G}$ is equicontinuos, then there exists $\delta_2>0$, such that for all $x,y\in X$ with $d(x,y)<\delta_2$,we have $|g(x)-g(y)|<\varepsilon$, for all $g\in \mathcal{G}$.

Choose $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, such that for all $x,y\in X$ with $d(x,y)<\delta$, we have
$|(f+g)(x)-(f+g)(y)|=|f(x)+g(x)-(f(y)+g(y))|=|f(x)-f(y)+g(x)-g(y)|\leq |f(x)-f(y)|+|g(x)-g(y)|<\varepsilon+\varepsilon=2\varepsilon$

Is it my work correct?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is X the normed space or really a metric space ? Because if it's a metric space, how do you defined the operation $+$ ?

Comment: Hint: the triangle inequality shows that $|(f+g)(x)-(f+g)(y)|\le |f(x)-f(y)|+|g(x)-g(y)|$.

Comment: @joshua OP is considering real values functions.

Comment: @joshua i don't know about $X$ is metric space or normed space. I only have information that $X$ is metric space. I have tried to prove that, but it ended by $|(f+g)(x)-(f+g)(y)|=|(f(x)+g(x))-(f(y)+g(y))|=|f(x)-f(y)+g(x)-g(y)|<|f(x)-f(y)|+|g(x)-g(y)|<\varepsilon$, which is not different with proof of summation of two continuous functions, so I am not sure my work is true..  :(

Comment: @David C. Ullrich I got that step, but I confused.. if I do like that, so what is the difference between the proof of sum of continuous functions and the sum of two equicontinuous families?

Comment: the inequalities in the two proofs are more or less the same; the difference is in the _quantifiers_ (for continuity $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$ and also on $f$ and $g$, while for equiconintuity it depends only on $\epsilon$).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I have added my work on my post. Is it right if I did like that? I am not sure when choosing $\delta$. And another question... Is it okay, if $f\in\mathcal{F}$ is $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g\in\mathcal{G}$ is $g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ (there is no different of $f$ and $g$)?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking with that last question, sorry

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich it's okay, thanks for helping me :)